# Computing the expectation of a product from the conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider 3 random variables $Y, W,X$. Suppose that we know
$$
(1) \quad \mathbb{E}(Y| X=x, W=w) \quad \text{ for each possible values $x,w$ taken by $X,W$}
$$
**Question:** Can we compute from such numbers
$$
\mathbb{E}(YX) \quad \quad \mathbb{E}(YW) \quad \quad \mathbb{E}(XW)
$$
If not, which additional information is it sufficient to compute such quantities in addition to knowing (1)?

---

**Some thoughts:**  For instance, it seems to me that to compute
$
\mathbb{E}(YX)
$ from $\mathbb{E}(Y|X, W)$ we need to know the joint distribution of $(X,W)$. In fact (assuming discrete random variables for simplicity),
$$
\mathbb{E}(YX)=\sum_{x}\sum_{y} xy \Pr(X=x, Y=y)\\
=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}\sum_w xy \Pr(X=x, Y=y, W=w)\\
=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}\sum_w xy \Pr(Y=y|X=x,W=w)\Pr(X=x,W=w)\\
=\sum_{x}\sum_w x\Pr(X=x,W=w) \sum_{y} y \Pr(Y=y|X=x,W=w)\\
=\sum_{x}\sum_w x\Pr(X=x,W=w) \mathbb{E}(Y|X=x, W=w)\\
$$
It seems a bit counterintuitive to me because I'm used to think that  conditional expectations offer more information than the expectations of products. Am I wrong?